# Return column constraints using Laravel Schema Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I can use the following to return an array of columns in my database table;

```
$column_names = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('tablename');
```

But is there a method to return the accepted values on each particular column? I have a lot of columns that are `enum`s for example and I would like to return those (perhaps in a multidimensional array) so I can use it in a Unit test.

Answer (score 0):

`getDoctrineColumn` is what you want.You can simply use the code below to get what you want:

```
$column_names = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('tablename');
foreach($column_names as $c){
    $type = DB::connection()->getDoctrineColumn('tablename', $c)->getType()->getName();
    // do anything you want with your desired type
}
```

Comment: this will return just their type eg "string", "integer" etc. not the "constraints" eg "once-a-week", "once-a-day" etc

Comment: @mike3875 you have asked for accepted values in your question. constraints are not accepted values. what do u mean by once-a-week? how is it set?

Comment: this is a line from my migration `$table->enum('gender', ['m', 'f', 'o'])->nullable();`. By accepted values I mean the 'm', 'f', or 'o'. Like this; https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Enum.